# Assignment type option prop to replace default option prop with correct return type

Tags: typescript, jwt, typescript-typings

I try to using `Omit` or `as const` but it still incorrect type.

```js
import JWT, {
  DecodeOptions,
  Secret,
  SignCallback,
  SignOptions,
  VerifyOptions,
  sign,
} from "jsonwebtoken"

export type paramJwtSign = Parameters<typeof sign>
export type jwtPayloadSign = paramJwtSign[0]

export interface jwtOptions {
  decodeOpt?: DecodeOptions
  signOpt?: SignOptions
  secret: Secret
  verifyOpt?: VerifyOptions
  payload?: jwtPayloadSign
}

export function jwt<D extends DecodeOptions>({
  decodeOpt,
  signOpt,
  secret,
  verifyOpt,
  payload: defPayload,
}: {
  decodeOpt?: D
  signOpt?: SignOptions
  secret: Secret
  verifyOpt?: VerifyOptions
  payload?: jwtPayloadSign
}) {
  return {
    decode: <T extends Parameters<typeof JWT.decode>>(
      token: string,
      options: T[1] = {},
    ) => {
      type Opt = Omit<D, keyof T[1]> & T[1]
      return JWT.decode(token, { ...decodeOpt, ...options } as Opt)
    },
  }
}
```

Normal [jsonwebtoken](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken)

```js
const token = "asdf"

const value_0_1 = JWT.decode(token) // string | JWT.JwtPayload | null
const value_0_2 = JWT.decode(token, { json: false }) // string | JWT.JwtPayload | null
const value_0_3 = JWT.decode(token, { json: true }) // JWT.JwtPayload | null
const value_0_4 = JWT.decode(token, { complete: false }) // string | JWT.JwtPayload | null
const value_0_5 = JWT.decode(token, { complete: true }) // JWT.Jwt | null
```

What it should be

```js
const objJwt1 = jwt({
  secret: Bun.env.JWT_KEY,
})
// type should like this
const value_1_1 = objJwt1.decode(token) // string | JWT.JwtPayload | null
const value_1_2 = objJwt1.decode(token, { json: false }) // string | JWT.JwtPayload | null
const value_1_3 = objJwt1.decode(token, { json: true }) // JWT.JwtPayload | null
const value_1_4 = objJwt1.decode(token, { complete: false }) // string | JWT.JwtPayload | null
const value_1_5 = objJwt1.decode(token, { complete: true }) // JWT.Jwt | null

const objJwt2 = jwt({
  secret: Bun.env.JWT_KEY,
  decodeOpt: { json: true },
})
// type should like this
const value_2_1 = objJwt2.decode(token) // JWT.JwtPayload | null
const value_2_2 = objJwt2.decode(token, { json: false }) // string | JWT.JwtPayload | null
const value_2_3 = objJwt2.decode(token, { json: true }) // JWT.JwtPayload | null
const value_2_4 = objJwt2.decode(token, { complete: false }) // JWT.JwtPayload | null => { complete: false, json: true }
const value_2_5 = objJwt2.decode(token, { complete: true }) // JWT.Jwt | null => { complete: true, json: true }

const objJwt3 = jwt({
  secret: Bun.env.JWT_KEY,
  decodeOpt: { complete: true },
})
// type should like this
const value_3_1 = objJwt3.decode(token) // JWT.Jwt | null
const value_3_2 = objJwt3.decode(token, { json: false }) // JWT.Jwt | null => { complete: true, json: false }
const value_3_3 = objJwt3.decode(token, { json: true }) // JWT.Jwt | null => { complete: true, json: true }
const value_3_4 = objJwt3.decode(token, { complete: false }) // string | JWT.JwtPayload | null
const value_3_5 = objJwt3.decode(token, { complete: true }) // JWT.Jwt | null
```